# How can I use the SimpleGenericOrifice of the Modelica Standard Library to impose pressure loss in a pipe?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fluid-dynamics

I would like to model an hydraulic network where I use the `Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice` as a seal so I can impose the pressure loss of a pipe. Using the formula in the documentation, I can calculate the zeta coefficient of the orifice.

Here is a simplified example, here I try to impose a pressure loss of 50 bar inside my pipe1. Because the pressure should be equal at the port, I assume that it should work :

[image]

However I don't have any pressure loss in the pipe and in the orifice.

Does anyone know how to make this work ?

Here is the code of the example

```
model Joints_HD

replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby
    Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 0.15, length = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, 42}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 328.15, p = 157e5, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-66, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 328.15, m_flow = -0.17, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {72, 10}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 0.15, length = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {44, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 0.15, dp_nominal = 5e+06, m_flow_nominal = 2.34e-9, use_zeta = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, diameter = 0.15, length = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, -18}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  
  connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-56, 10}, {-48, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, orifice.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-28, 10}, {-8, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe2.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{54, 10}, {62, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(orifice.port_b, pipe2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, 10}, {34, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-28, 10}, {-20, 10}, {-20, -18}, {-8, -18}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, pipe2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{12, -18}, {26, -18}, {26, 10}, {34, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));

end Joints_HD;
```

Best regards,
Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pipe1` has "wrong" dimensions (diameter, length, roughness etc.) since it only creates a very small pressure drop.

To verify that the rest of the model is okay — and that you can have a pressure drop of 50 bar over `pipe1` at the flow set in `boundary1` (0.17 kg/s) — temporarilly change `pipe1.FlowModel` to `NominalTurbulentPipeFlow` with `m_flow_nominal=0.17` and `dp_nominal=50 bar`.

Subsequently, switch the flow model back to the default (detailed) model and adjust the pipe geometry.

By the way, you should provide a value for `orifice.zeta` even though it is not used.